# Vector space without a scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples, applications

In linear algebra the terms vector space and [scalar product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) always (at least for me) appear together. Can you give me an example of a vector space without a scalar product?
Does the sentence *Let $V$ be a vector space without a scalar product* make any sense? Have it any application in mathematics?

Comment: Over say the reals, for any vector space one can define an inner product. The proof I am thinking of uses the Axiom of Choice, and perhaps *requires* (some of) it.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a terminology problem.

By definition, a vector space always has a **scalar multiplication**, where you multiply a vector with a scalar and get a vector.

However, vector spaces can optionally come with a **inner product** (or **dot product**) where you multiply two vectors and get a scalar.

The latter operation is not required for vector spaces, and it is easy to make a vector space without one -- just don't define it. For example "the vector space of infinite sequences of real numbers, with coordinatewise addition and (scalar) multiplication".

"Scalar product" could in principle mean either concept, but would most often be an inner product.

Whenever we have a vector space, we can use the Axiom of Choice to prove that it is possible to choose *some* inner product that satisfies the required axioms. But, as the words are usually used, the vector space doesn't "have" an inner product until we decide to make such a choice.

Comment: It's not true that an arbitrary vector space admits an inner product. It has to be a real or complex vector space. Now, this doesn't necessarily stop you from producing a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on your vector space (but it would not necessarily be an inner product if the vector space is complex as complex inner products have to be sesquilinear).

Comment: @kahen: I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) that "vector space" for the OP implies a real or complex one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Are there vector spaces that are not real or complex? Are you including vector spaces over finite fields in this category?

Comment: @alfC: Since you know vector spaces over other fields exist, why are you asking? Do you have a point that's different from Kahen's comment?

Comment: @HenningMakholm because I always thought that finite prime fields were are also considered real (because they are made up of real numbers.) Hence my confusion in my other question in SO.

Answer (score 3):

You firstly want your underlying field to be characteristic $0$ (else the condition $\langle x,x\rangle = 0$ may have nontrivial solutions). The simplest fields of characteristic $0$ are $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$. If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, you can define an inner product on it in a way similar to the Euclidean inner product. Even if you do not explicitly state that there is an inner product on the set, it still exists. So in this setting, it is not possible.

We must then venture into the realm of infinite dimensional vector spaces, and here it is easily possible. Let's take our vector space $V$ to be the set of sequences of real numbers such that the sequence is bounded, i.e. if $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence, then $\sup_n |x_n| < \infty$. There is not an inner product on this vector space that is compatible with the norm structure.

That said, one can define an inner product on this vector space but it will not be compatible with the norm structure. Suppose $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are in $V$, then define $\langle (x_n),(y_n)\rangle$ by

$$\langle (x_n),(y_n)\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}x_ny_n.$$

This is an inner product on $V$. The existence of the norm is not an accident and this leads to H. Malcolm's answer above.